# Error when trying to insert inside a DateTime field in database mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I tried doing this after going through many forums,

```
$date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$query = "INSERT INTO temp_order(user_id ,item_id ,name ,price ,quantity, date) VALUES ({$_GET['cust_id']},{$_GET['item']},'{$content['name']}',{$content['price']},{$_GET['quan']},{$date})";
```

But still getting this error " You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '09:23:12)' at line 1".

I don't know what that means. Here date column inside database has type of 'datetime'.

Comment: Do not insert variables directly into the query string.
Use something like Zend_Db to `->quote()` the variables first, or use its `->insert()` method.

Comment: @Pekka i tried using $dates, but still getting the same error

Comment: Your actual problem is that you're missing the quotes around `'{$date}'`, but you'd be much better off using mysqli or pdo with parameterized queries instead.

Comment: @Pekka웃: nah, [see the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html): _"MySQL permits some keywords to be used as unquoted identifiers because many people previously used them. Examples are those in the following list: ... `DATE`.."_.

Comment: @Wrikken ah, nice! Didn't know that.

Comment: @Pekka. So now do you. Perhaps consider removing or revising your comment.

Comment: @Pekka웃: hehe, I always assumed them to be reserved too, until good ol' Bill Karwin pointed it out to me ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though your date value is unquoted and it (the sql) looks thus to the database

```
..., 09:23:12)
```

which won't work. Try a) inspecting the actual value before using it, making sure it is quoted (if you have to use a string) and/or b) use one of the mysql built-in conversion functions so that you are passing a date object and not some kind of string.

e.g `STR_TO_DATE` documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Comment: But when i echo out $date, it is giving this 2013-06-30 09:30:19, which i think is suitable for datetime field.

Comment: Since MySQL automatically converts strings using the same method as `STR_TO_DATE`, why is that necessary?

Comment: @Barmar: because it's bad practice to mix data types. Always assign a date object to a date field etc. And you want to know asap if your supposed value is valid or not, before you send stuff over the wire.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing quotes around the date. It should be:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO temp_order(user_id ,item_id ,name ,price ,quantity, date)
          VALUES ({$_GET['cust_id']},{$_GET['item']},'{$content['name']}',
                  {$content['price']},{$_GET['quan']},'{$date}')";
```